# How can I retrieve indptr, indices from scipy csr_matrix?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, csr, csc

According to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) of `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`, there are many ways to create a `csr_matrix`. One of the ways is to give `data`, `indptr`, and `indices` as inputs. I wonder, if there is a way to retrieve them in the opposite direction, i.e., assume that I have `my_csr_matrix` created as below:

```
>>> indptr = np.array([0, 2, 3, 6])
>>> indices = np.array([0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 2])
>>> data = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> my_csr_matrix = csr_matrix((data, indices, indptr), shape=(3, 3))
>>> my_csr_matrix.toarray()
array([[1, 0, 2],
       [0, 0, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]])
```

The question is, how can I retrieve indptr and indices from `my_csr_matrix` without knowing the information about them or `data` before-hand explicitly?

Comment: `csr_matrix` is a class.  It's listed attributes can be accessed just like the attributes of any other python class.  For what it's worth, are most often sparse matrices are created with `row/col/data` inputs.  They are easiest to understand.  But the `indptr/indices/data` attributes are accessed in the same way.  Experiement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Literally just `my_csr_matrix.indptr` and `my_csr_matrix.indices`. You can also get the data array with `my_csr_matrix.data`.

These attributes are documented further down the page, under the "Attributes" heading.

Note that these are the actual underlying arrays used by the sparse matrix representation. Modifying these arrays will modify the sparse matrix, unless you do something that causes the CSR matrix to allocate new underlying arrays. (For example, `my_csr_matrix[1, 1] = 7` would change the sparsity structure of the matrix and require allocating new arrays.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for such a clear answer. I should try to read through the whole document carefully.